# Making the background of a picture transparent using opencv

Tags: image, opencv

I have looked through most of the other related questions, and most of them dont apply to my code.

I am creating a 2D racing game, and i have to add 2 car images to my background image, in order to do this i had to load the images as `Mat` (I was able to make it work like that).

The problem is not that my cars (.png) have a fuchsia background and i want to make it transparent. Most of the solutions involve loading the images as `IplImage`which i tried and somehow ruined other parts of my code.

```
 #include <opencv\cv.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <opencv\highgui.h>
 #include <iostream>


 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat car1, car2, BKGR;

int key = 0;

/* load images and checks if correct images loaded */
 BKGR = imread("map.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //937x768
car1 = imread("car1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //70x75
car2 = imread("car2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //70x75

if((!BKGR.data)||(!car1.data)||(!car2.data))
    cout << "Could not open one or more images." << endl;
else 
    cout << "Images were loaded succesfully." << endl;
    waitKey(0);

    car1.copyTo(BKGR.colRange(450,520).rowRange(630,705));
    car2.copyTo(BKGR.colRange(350,420).rowRange(430,505));
    waitKey(0);

    cv::floodFill(car1, cv::Point(150,150), cv::Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));
    cv::floodFill(car2, cv::Point(150,150), cv::Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));

/* create a window, display the result, wait for a key */
cvNamedWindow("Game", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Game", BKGR);


cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
 }
```

So if you guys know a way of making the background of the image transparent without using `IplImage` I would really be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find similar kind of example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html#adding-images)

And if you need load transparent image(with alpha) use

`imread("map.jpg",-1)`

instead of

`imread("map.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`

which will load alpha, See [OpenCV Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) for more info.

Comment: Do the images need to be converted to BGRA in order to access the alpha (or are they already because they are PNG)? Because if I apply it directly to my code it gives me an error after loading the images.

Comment: You can check number of channel after loading image using Mat.channels(). If three channel you can create Mat with 4 channel.